# Problem with installing web3 using npm

Tags: npm

I am trying to install web3 on my ubuntu 18.04 system. I am using the following command:

```
@lc2530hz:~$ sudo npm install -g web3
```

but I am getting the error:

> sudo: npm: command not found

But when I am typing:
@lc2530hz:~$ npm --version
6.14.6

Kindly guide me how to install web3.

Zulfi.

Comment: If you manually installed Node, then you will need to softlink each installed binary into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. Alternatively, you can remove Node from your system and install it again with `sudo apt install npm`, which will ensure paths and links are all correct.

Comment: Please guide me how to do this soft linking?